# Bounded Type compile error in java8

Tags: java, generics

These two examples don't compile using Oracle Java 8 JDK.

The error is:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer
>       for (Integer i : foo.set )

Example 1)

```
import java.util.Set;

class Foo<T>
{
    protected Set<Integer> set;
}

class Foo2 extends Foo
{
    void doit()
    {
        for (Integer i : set )
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Example 2)

```
import java.util.Set;

class Foo<T>
{
    public Set<Integer> set;
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        for (Integer i : foo.set )
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Is it bug or feature? As I can understand generics don't work in fields оf raw  type.

Comment: Strangely, this does compile if you construct `Foo` as a typed object, even if it's not typed as `Integer` - say, `Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>();`

Comment: It is possibly because you use a raw type, all type information is erased on all its containing fields, e.g. `Set<Integer>` becomes `Set`.

Comment: Why do you use raw types anyway?

Comment: @MCEmperor    it was bug in real code (after refactoring generics were added in ancestor class, but forget about descendants )   and I was need some time to found reason - it was not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error. You need to pass a generic type to create new instance:

```
class Foo<T>
{
  public Set<Integer> set;
  public static void main( String[] args ) {

      Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo();  // changed code

      for (Integer i : foo.set )
      {

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The point was  that the type parameter `T` isn't actually being used. The error wasn't on creating a new instance, the code in the question just creates a raw type.

Comment: I understand this, I made raw type consciously. Raw types is not forbidden in java.  And here Set<Integer> it's not raw type, it's inside raw Foo. Compiler  ignore all field types in raw object Foo. It's strange.

Comment: @DenisPimenov **Don't. Ever. Use. Raw types.** The only reason they're not forbidden is because of backward compatibility. But when writing new code, **always** use type parameters. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/507738). Plus, even the [JLS, §4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) states that it might *"disallow the use of raw types"*.

Comment: @DenisPimenov What is strange about it? It is documented, that when using a raw version of a generic class, then ___every___ generic type in that class will be erased. So you don't have `Set<Integer>`, you have `Set`.